# Generating database and connection from schema

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, database-schema

I'm using **Glassfish server 4.0** as my app server for a java project in **NetBeans 7.3.1**. I have a database schema which I would like to include in my server as a database. Is there a way to generate the database in Glassfish based on a previous schema?

The extensions of the files are `.frm` and there's one `.opt` file.

Also, does **Glassfish** include a visual interface to modify a database's table's properties and registries?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your the last part of your question is no. Glassfish itself does not include a visual interface for modifying database tables, properties etc. It includes a visual interface for creating JDBC Connection Pools and JDBC Resources.  I personally use one integrated into my IDE of choice, Netbeans may have this feature, I happen to use IDEA. In production you could use any 3rd party app that does this, TOAD being a popular one but there are many.

I have some thoughts on the first part of your question but nothing ready to put into an answer at this point. When I do I'll update this one if its still an open question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll be waiting for the update.